# SSRS Prior Month, MTD Same period as current month -1 Day

Tags: reporting-services

If today is 5/2 I want to see last month's data for 4/1.
For tomorrow on 5/3 I want to see last month's data for 4/2, etc
I want to modify the code to not show me today's value for same time last month, I want the day before today.

I got this far from another question asked here. 
[SSRS Prior Month, MTD Same period as current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249713/ssrs-prior-month-mtd-same-period-as-current-month)

```
 =sum(IIf(Year(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = Year(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(-3)) And Month(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = Month(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(-3)) AND DatePart("d", Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) <= Dateadd("d",-1, Now), Fields!Application_Count.Value, Nothing), )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a new data set (assuming you are using SQL  as your data source) and create a default date you are after.. simple as this:

```
select dateadd(day,-1, dateadd(month,-1, convert(date,getdate()))) as default_date
```

Then use this date as your parameter for your report.

That is the start date.. not clear as to what you want your end date to be..

Comment: Thanks @Harry, that's not a bad idea. I ended up going with this... this formula I am looking back 3 months as same time frame of current month -1 day. so 5/1 compared to 2/1...=sum(IIf(Year(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = 
Year(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(-3)) And 
Month(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = Month(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(-3)) AND 
DatePart("d", Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) <=day(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(-3)), 
Fields!Application_Count.Value, Nothing), )